# What is the mean of barrier sense or viscosity sense?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

Pictures below are from [Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf). I don't know what is the mean of barrier sense or viscosity sense. At beginning, I guess they should be the concepts of real analysis. But in the indexes of Rudin's Real and Complex analysis, I can't find them.

In Evans' Partial Differential Equations, there are *barrier* and *viscosity solution*. But seemly, they are not connection with the barrier sense or viscosity sense.

If this problem is fussy,  telling me to read what book or paper is enough. Thanks.

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: In addition, lots of excellent references can be found in the Bamler’ website. You can make good use of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Bamler’s lecture notes will give you some help.
See link below [https://math.berkeley.edu/~rbamler/rfclass.html](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Erbamler/rfclass.html)

The barrier sense, roughly speaking means we can investigate a smooth function instead of a lower regularity function such as lipschitz continuous. For example when we consider the distance function on the space time. Some details can also be found in the book “Notes on Perelman’s papers” written by Bruce Kleiner and John Lott. The viscosity sense comes from the viscosity solution you may also find in many PDE articles.

Comment: Thanks, Notes on Perelman’s papers   is good.